# How to use jquery.validate with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
require.config({  
    paths:{  
        jquery:"lib/jquery-1.12.3.min",  
        bootstrap:"lib/bootstrap.min",  
        validate:"lib/jquery.validate.min"  
    },  
    shim:{  
        bootstrap:['jquery'],  
        validate:['jquery']    
    }  
});      


require(['jquery','validate'],function(){  
    alert("hope it works");  
});
```

The alert method can not work.
However, if I remove 'validate' in

```
require(['jquery','validate'],function(){  
     alert("hope it works");  
});
```

just like this:

```
require(['jquery'],function(){  
     alert("hope it works");  
});
```

Then, the alert method works.
This suggests to me there's an issue with the validate library and RequireJs together.
I'm sure I'm doing something trivial wrong.
I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: it is working as expected. working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p15nn7jb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is working as expected.

WOrking fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p15nn7jb/

```
require.config({  
    paths:{  
        jquery:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery",  
        bootstrap:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min",  
        validate:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min"  
    },  
    shim:{  
        bootstrap:['jquery'],  
        validate:['jquery']    
    }  
});      


require(['jquery','validate'],function(){  
    alert("hope it works");  
});
```

Also refer to the below link which is using jquery validation with require js

https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/requirejs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

have a similar bug 
only i want to use the localized messages
cant make it work with cdn only local

```
    require.config({  
paths:{  
    jquery:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery",    
    validate:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min",  
    messages_he:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/localization/messages_he.min"  
},  
shim:{  
    bootstrap:['jquery'],  
    validate:['jquery']    
    }  
});      


require(['jquery','validate'],function(){  
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () {
            console.log("submitted!");
        }
    });
    $("form").validate();
});
```

but this local works ok

```
require.config({  
paths:{  
    jquery:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery",    
    validate:"libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min",  
    messages_he:"libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/localization/messages_he.min"  
},  
shim:{  
    bootstrap:['jquery'],  
    validate:['jquery']    
    }  
});      

require(['jquery', paths.jqueryval, paths.messages_he],function(){  
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () {
            console.log("submitted!");
        }
    });
    $("form").validate();
});
```